# ajax issue to display the content of a simply doc

Tags: html, ajax

I want to do something really simple with ajax. I have a folder in my mac with 2 documents : index.html and text.txt.

index.html :

```
<p>
  <input type="button" onclick="loadDoc()" value="CLICK" />
</p>

<p id="fileContent"></p>



<script>

  function loadDoc() {

      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

      xhr.open('GET', "text.txt", true);

      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { 

              document.getElementById('fileContent').innerHTML = xhr.responseText; 

      }
      xhr.send(null); 
  }
</script>
```

text.txt :

```
hello
```

When the user click on the button CLICK, I want the content of text.txt 'hello' appear bellow the button CLICK.

It's doesnt work with my mac locally. Do you know why?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax requests cannot be made over `file:///` This is a security restriction of [CORS](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCwQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fenable-cors.org%2F&ei=yoQ1VP67LOXC8QHB2YHYBQ&usg=AFQjCNHlg8-BWkyp3Mrs2Cv_9WtGfi05UQ&sig2=o4bzERgv6-ea29oiM10gcg&bvm=bv.76943099,d.b2U).

What you have is correct. But needs to be served through `http://`

Answer (score 1):

That's normal behavior for most browsers. Local files cannot be accessed by ajax. It's a security feature. You can ether run some dev server or start chrome with  --disabled-web-security flag. There is however a new html5 local file access API coming along, tho i'm not sure how well it's supported yet.. http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/